# count(*) in mysql returning only one record

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I want to count how many records from another table in the same select statement  , i used Left join
and in the select statement i put **count(ag.*)** 
see the 
Example :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select("a.answer_id,a.date_added , count(ag.content_id) AS agree_count")
            ->from('Answer a')
             ->leftJoin("a.Agree ag ON a.answer_id = ag.content_id AND ag.content_type = 'answer' ")
            ->where('a.question_id= ? ', $questionId)
```

But its only returning the first record, can i Fix that? or to make another table and make it only for counting ?

Comment: You have a where clause that fixes `question_id`. Are you sure that there are more rows to be exspected?

Comment: What output were you hoping for? Do you want the agree_count attribute to count the entire list and be in every single row as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` in your query.

More infos [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

When you don't have a GROUP BY clause, it's normal to get only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Count(*) will only return one record if you don't use Group By. You are asking it to count all the records, so there can be only one result.

Answer (score 0):

The count() SQL function changes how results are returned from the database - without a `GROUP BY` the database will only return one record, regardless of other colums in the `SELECT`.

if you add:

```
group by a.answer_id
```

to the end of your SQL query, that might DWYM.